# Is it must to add app in playstore for using android app actions?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

Referred a link: https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin

but when run the app in device, receiving a message "Sorry, can't found". So, looks like the action may work when uploading app in the play store which is of no use for now.

Is there any other way to check app actions for testing?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Please try [this checklist](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/135714718#comment60) to isolate other possible causes. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Diego - You're pointing to a Google-internal-only page.

Comment: Good catch @Prisoner. Could you please update the link above with this one? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135714718#comment60 Thanks!